# Jquery, how to retrieve the contents of a select dropdown (not the value)

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, select-menu

I am currently using the following script to pull records from my mysql database using ajax. It works just fine and uses the stockID as the value for the select and then takes several of the table fields to build the value the user sees. e.g :

```
<option value="454545454">Bridgestone 215/45/18 tyre</option
```

.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#customer').on('change', function (){
    $('#vehicle').html("<option value=''>Select</option>");// add this on each call then add the options when data receives from the request
            $.getJSON('select.php', {customerId: $(this).val()}, function(data){
                var options = '';
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    options += '<option value="' + data[x]['id'] + '">' + data[x]['reg'] + ' - ' + data[x]['make'] + ' - ' + data[x]['model'] + '</option>';
                }
                $('#vehicle').html(options);
              $("select").select2();
            });
                                        });


    $('#customer, #vehicle').on('change', function (){
          $('#qty1').val('');
          $('#linetotal1').text('');
          $("#stock1").val($("#stock1 option:first").val());
            $('#qty2').val('');
            $('#linetotal2').text('');
             $("#stock2").val($("#stock2 option:first").val());
              $('#qty3').val('');
              $('#linetotal3').text('');
               $("#stock3").val($("#stock3 option:first").val());
                $('#qty4').val('');
                $('#linetotal4').text('');
                 $("#stock4").val($("#stock4 option:first").val());
                  $('#qty5').val('');
                  $('#linetotal5').text('');
                   $("#stock5").val($("#stock5 option:first").val());
                  $('#qty6').val('');
                  $('#linetotal6').text('');
                   $("#stock6").val($("#stock6 option:first").val());
         }); 

         });
    </script>
```

The next piece of script then takes the values of the selected dropdown and put the stockID out of 'value' in the select into a text box called stock1T etc.

```
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#stock1').change(function() {
                  $('#stock1T').val($('#stock1 option:selected').val());
                  $('#description1').val($('#stock1 option:selected').val());
             });
              $('#stock2').change(function() {
                  $('#stock2T').val($('#stock2 option:selected').val());
                  $('#description2').val($('#stock2 option:selected').val());
             });
              $('#stock3').change(function() {
                  $('#stock3T').val($('#stock3 option:selected').val());
                  $('#description3').val($('#stock3 option:selected').val());
             });
              $('#stock4').change(function() {
                  $('#stock4T').val($('#stock4 option:selected').val());
                  $('#description4').val($('#stock4 option:selected').val());
             });
              $('#stock5').change(function() {
                  $('#stock5T').val($('#stock5 option:selected').val());
                  $('#description5').val($('#stock5 option:selected').val());
             });
              $('#customer').change(function() {
                  $('#customerID').val($('#customer option:selected').val());
             });
     });
    </script>
```

Iv now created another text box in that row called description1 , 2 , 3 etc, but im not sure how to pull the description in between the option and /option tags into those text boxes ?.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out myself in the end ! :

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#stock1').change(function() {
          $('#stock1T').val($('#stock1 option:selected').val());
          $('#description1').val($('#stock1 option:selected').text());
     });
      $('#stock2').change(function() {
          $('#stock2T').val($('#stock2 option:selected').val());
          $('#description2').val($('#stock2 option:selected').text());
     });
      $('#stock3').change(function() {
          $('#stock3T').val($('#stock3 option:selected').val());
          $('#description3').val($('#stock3 option:selected').text());
     });
      $('#stock4').change(function() {
          $('#stock4T').val($('#stock4 option:selected').val());
          $('#description4').val($('#stock4 option:selected').text());
     });
      $('#stock5').change(function() {
          $('#stock5T').val($('#stock5 option:selected').val());
          $('#description5').val($('#stock5 option:selected').text());
     });
      $('#customer').change(function() {
          $('#customerID').val($('#customer option:selected').text());
     });
    });
</script>
```